# Can't select a Radio button in a Razor page

Tags: c#, radio-button, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a razor page with 2 radio buttons. But I can't check one of them...

```
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" asp-for="@Model.ActionNeeded" value="Yes" class="custom-control-input"  name="radio-stacked" required>
    <label class="custom-control-label">Yes</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-3">
    <input type="radio" asp-for="@Model.ActionNeeded" value="No" class="custom-control-input"  name="radio-stacked" required>
    <label class="custom-control-label">No</label>
</div>
```

[image]

What am I missing?? It's a simple thing but can't have it working...

Comment: Your radios don't have a value, add a value and see if you can select them now.

Comment: I think it a css issue. Your label be positioned below  or covered by some other div. Check the css of laber or radio.

Comment: Its a copied from the bootstrap website

Comment: `asp-for="@Model.ActionNeeded"` is generating the same id for both radios, create a different id for each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asp-for="@Model.ActionNeeded"` is generating the same id for both radios.

Create a different id for each radio and add a `for=""` in the label

```
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="ActionYes" value="Yes" class="custom-control-input"  name="ActionNeeded" required>
    <label for="ActionYes" class="custom-control-label">Yes</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-3">
    <input type="radio" id="ActionNo" value="No" class="custom-control-input"  name="ActionNeeded" required>
    <label for="ActionNo" class="custom-control-label">No</label>
</div>
```

Comment: @user7849697 I believe the model binder use the name attribute to automatically map the html to the property. Can you check if `name="ActionNeeded"` works now?

Answer (score 1):

You have both buttons with the same name, and that makes you lose a value of them:

```
name="radio-stacked"
```

Comment: I removed the name but still can't select a RadioButton

Comment: you have to put a different name for each one, or if you don't put in, you have to look for the name that is generated.

Comment: Added a name but still can't select a RadioButton :D

Comment: The radio has to have the same name to be treated as a group

Comment: if you want to create them as a group you have to add different value in each one

Comment: if you add value, in your code you can get the value like :  Request["radio-stacked"].ToString()